# Disable Touchbar for my application (and make function keys always visible)

Tags: swift, macos, nstouchbar, macbookpro-touch-bar

I have written a macOS app which uses a lot the function keys. I need to include the Touch Bar support but for the moment I would like to set the function keys as default, so the app is still fully usable.

How can I do that?

Comment: There is no API to force display the function keys. It is up to the user to do it by hitting `fn` on the keyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that I have found a solution. There is a macOS setting which allows to do exactly what I am looking for, so in order to get the behaviour I want I have only to make my app change programmatically that setting.

[image]

Comment: Did you find a way to programmatically change this setting?

Comment: I didn't need to do it anymore so I haven't look further into it